# How can I remove my NullPointerException?

Tags: android, kotlin

I retry to post my question because I don't have receive an answer : my app close itself when i click, an I find as cause that :

```
    Process: fr.amseu.mystretching, PID: 15005
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fr.amseu.mystretching/fr.amseu.mystretching.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3556)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3703)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2216)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at fr.amseu.mystretching.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:17)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7955)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7944)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3531)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3703) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2216) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

As context, I give my Main activity :

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val exerciseButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton)

        exerciseButton.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

My layout which contain the Image button. It is a part of a recycler view if it change anything ? :

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/lower_legs"
            android:contentDescription="@string/home_page_first_button" />
```

And I have finally my second activity (as a kotlin class file), where the click should redirect me :

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercices)
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help...

Comment: imageButton is present in `activity_main` right?

Comment: Please don’t repost questions. Update the existing one with additional detail.

Comment: @dinkar_kumar yes it is

Comment: @Tenfour04 ok sorry

Answer (score 0):

> My layout which contain the Image button. It is a part of a recycler view if it change anything ?

It does change a lot. You're trying to find a view that does not exist when `onCreate` is called because you have not initialized the recycler view or its adapter (as far as the code you showed).

See this post for handling a click on a RecyclerView item: [RecyclerView onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick)